# How to pack nested conditions(for a SQL query) into data structures(using list<string> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I have built a **Query Engine** for dynamically querying the database using C# (ADO.NET). 
I have provided C# GUI to select various columns and provided options for querying "Select"  dynamically.
I just have to select column names and  provide value from the various user controls provided.
The final Query is collected in a Text box(contains the entire SQL query) and the query is sent to SQL server with a help of a button which provides connection between Database and the GUI.The output is displayed on the DatagridView provided.

**My Question is**- How can i pack nested conditions into data structures(using list).
I want this to be added to the Application(Query Engine) i have created.
Can Anyone help me on this? Advance thanks :)

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @TomT - i have built a qury builder already, what i need to do is add nested queries to datstructure such as list<string>. query=string,list<string>. where string is the name of column and list<string> is the condition to be applied. I have to use where In clause to add nested conditions

Comment: You need to post the code so we can see what you are doing.